# PHP and MySQL - Unique Set of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am compiling a database that contains a structure/data like so:

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
-----------------------------------
0  |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d
1  |   a   |   b   |   d   |   c
2  |   a   |   c   |   b   |   d
```

I want to eliminate duplicate sets, so in the example above, all three rows have the same four values (except for `id`, obviously) so I would like to eliminate all duplicate sets. Is there a fast/elegant way to do this?

What I'm doing right now is sorting each set alphabetically, saving to array, then comparing arrays. This works fine when you have 100's of rows but I know it's not efficient enough to run datasets of 1000's or millions of rows....

**EDIT:**

Expected output:

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
-----------------------------------
0  |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d
```

It really does matter the column or order, as long as there is only one unique set. The mysql UNIQUE constraint would not work here unless I am missing something...

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a79b/3/0)

Comment: So all 3 rows will be deleted?

Comment: Please define duplicate sets, does the column matter? Do the duplicates have to be in the same column?

Comment: which one would you keep? And what is the range of possible values?

Comment: please post how your expected ouput should be?

Comment: You either need SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY, depending on whether you want to use aggregate functions, like COUNT(), SUM() etc.

Comment: Why the close vote? I've edited the question to address the first few comments.....and no, SELECT DISTINCT nor GROUP BY would solve this.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a79b/3/0

Comment: Okay I see what you meant. Retired the answer.

Comment: Of what datatype are the columns?

Comment: They are VARCHAR(128)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure MySQL answer:

I've extended your sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
col_1 VARCHAR(128),
col_2 VARCHAR(128),
col_3 VARCHAR(128),
col_4 VARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'a','b','c','d'),(2,'a','b','d','c'),(3,'a','d','c','b'),(4,'a','c','d','b'),(5,'e','f','g','h'),(6,'f','h','g','e')
;

SELECT * FROM test;

+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | a     | b     | c     | d     |
|  2 | a     | b     | d     | c     |
|  3 | a     | d     | c     | b     |
|  4 | a     | c     | d     | b     |
|  5 | e     | f     | g     | h     |
|  6 | f     | h     | g     | e     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

A helper table comes into play:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_test;
CREATE TABLE tmp_test (id int, col varchar(128));

INSERT INTO tmp_test
SELECT id, col_1 FROM test
UNION
SELECT id, col_2 FROM test
UNION
SELECT id, col_3 FROM test
UNION
SELECT id, col_4 FROM test
;
```

Then I truncate the original table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE test;

ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

so that it can be refilled with the "distinct" values:

```
INSERT INTO test (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(gc, '@', 1), SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(gc, '@', 2) FROM LOCATE('@', gc) + 1), SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(gc, '@', 3) FROM LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(gc, '@', 3))), REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(gc), '@', 1))
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    GROUP_CONCAT(col ORDER BY col SEPARATOR '@') AS gc
    FROM tmp_test
    GROUP BY id
) sq;

SELECT * FROM test;

+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | a     | b     | c     | d     |
|  2 | e     | f     | g     | h     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: this appears to be exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, will test tonight and mark answer as accepted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP solution:

```
$distinct = array();
$duplicates = array();

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 FROM my_table");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = array_shift($row);
    $row = asort($row);
    $key = implode('.', $row);

    if (isset($distinct[$key])) {
        $duplicates[] = $id;
    } else {
        $distinct[$key] = $id;
    }
}

$pdo->beginTransaction();

$idToBeDeleted = 0;

$stmt = $pdo->query("DELETE FROM my_table WEHRE id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $idToBeDeleted, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate) {
    $idToBeDeleted = $duplicate;
    $stmt->execute();
}

$pdo->commit();
```

If you have many rows in the database you may do commits after chunks of 10.000 deletes.

Please note that this code was not tested and may be some changes to be done in order to work.